External truth of some sentences in first-order arithmetic
I have been pondering a way to understand semantic truth for first-order arithmetic. We know that there cannot be a decidable truth-predicate for first-order arithmetic and we also know that there exist non-standard model's of PA. (That being said, from the finite meta-theory, all we can say is PA is incomplete if consistent; the existence of non-standard models is in the realm of Set Theory.)
I used to be a platonist with number theory because, however, the more I read other philosophers perspectives, the further I stray from that notion. For now, I am sympathetic as a nominalist in the same manner as Azzouni; we do not discover abstract objects, but create them. Any truths about the objects are true in the framework that we proposed their existence, but do not refer to any external object.
Here, true simply means syntactically true within a formal language. That being, said, it is still hard to shake the feeling of number theoretic sentences having an external truth value especially since "all" of the "objects" can be accessed or constructed in a finite amount of time, count and then stop. The use of quantifiers inhibits one from creating a Turing machine that decides a truth value. However, with the following thought experiment, I describe why we might believe that sentences have a semantic truth value for sentences up to two alternating quantifiers.
Consider first a sentence with one universal quantifier, for all x, P(x), then the formula P(x) in the scope of the quantifier is decidable in a finite amount of time. One can build a Turing machine that iterates through 0,1,2,... and calculates the value of the inner formula.  If it ever calculates a F, the program will terminate. We can physically or mentally run an initial segment of this program for any amount of time we want but we can never "complete" it all. But this program is deterministic; every time we run the same initial segment, we will always get the same sequence. And for any n, every sequence of size n will be identical. Because of it is deterministic, is it untrue to believe that the sequence will either terminate or not terminate even if we will never constructively know? The use of "believe" vs. "know" is an important distinction to recognize. In other words, if I claim that the sentence is true, then I am making a promise that you can read through the sequence for any duration of time, and you will always read T.
Furthermore, suppose we have a sentence with two quantifiers; for example for all x, there exists a y s.t. P(x,y). We build a machine that has two states, first it will start at x=0 and iterate through y=0,1,2.... For every F calculated, the value of x is added to the output sequence. Once a T is calculated, the value x is incremented by one, and printed on the tape. Then y begins to iterate from y=0,1,2,... again. We say that this sentence is true, if for any number x, there is a point in time n that the number x occurs in the sequence. And to be clear, on the quantifiers in the previous sentence, I mean that if you count up to any number and then stop, I promise you that if you read through the outputted sequence you will eventually find that number. We DO NOT constructively know whether or not this promise is true or reliable. But the promise is about what is possible in a finite amount of time.
This experiment is valid for the natural numbers but much less for Set Theory. The use of Power Set and Choice create "ghost sets"; objects that are not accessible, constructible or well defined intuitively.
Are there philosophies of mathematics that would reject these thought experiments? That is, the "truth" of these sentences (in the way I defined it as an operation and promise) is not external. We surely cannot just choose a value, right? Because, then we could choose either T or F and the finite promises of those two choices will contradict each other. Does this mean that sentences like the Twin-Prime Conjecture will still have a truth value, regardless if it is independent from first-order PA?

Re your newly converted belief "we do not discover abstract objects, but create them. Any truths about the objects are true in the framework that we proposed their existence, but do not refer to any external object", the famous Riemann Hypothesis is known to be equivalent to a Σ1 PA sentence (Chowla showed that the generalized Riemann hypothesis implies that the first prime in the arithmetic progression a mod m is at most Km^2log(m)^2 for some fixed constant K). Then under your new belief, truth of objects in the invented PA don't refer or map to truth/falsity of external object like RH?...

This 'thought experiment' is well-known and is often used to argue that Π2 sentences of PA, like the twin prime conjecture, are 'true' when undecidable in PA, see e.g. Gaifman, On Ontology and Realism in Mathematics, p. 487. As he notes, "realism with respect to natural numbers is inevitable? No. Finitist and intuitionist positions deny that the picture of “running through all the numbers” is a basis for treating the sentences in question as factually meaningful."

@DoubleKnot well, I guess you have to be specific in every case. I'm not entirely read on this position yet. But I assume that it would be something like, RH has a truth value under my description of number and truth. But this is clearly different from what I mean when I quantify over the numbers in a formal system for PA.

@Conifold I agree with Gaifman if you are taking the perspective from a finitist or intuitionist. I guess, the belief aspect comes in because it is not justified through demonstration but merely irrefutability. If both finite promises could be true then we would get a contradiction. These Turing machines are not in a formal system but we still have something like not (A and not A). Finitist would simply say it just doesn't have a meaning to say those promises have a value at all.

@Conifold It seems like these kinds of assertions are on the same level as first-order PA is consistent. At first, it appears that finitists do not hold that this sentence has any meaning. But, if one were to demonstrate a proof of contradiction from PA, then that sentence would have a meaning. So we are left unknowing for now. That is, we are agnostic. Would it be absurd to believe there is a truth value beyond us ever knowing it finitistically? Surely it must be one case or another. PA is either consistent or it is not; we can proof a contradiction, or not.

This is very different from saying we can prove A or prove not A, which would be the criteria for excluding the middle in this case from a finitistic perspective.

Your question is similar to this post. Basically Constructivism/Intuitionism and Formalism reject your notion of semantic external (believed) truth which is a Platonic idea because it relies on non-constructive reasoning. They would question the meaningfulness of truth claims for sentences about infinite processes without explicit constructive procedures. Thus they'll be more conservative than Platonists to speculate the truth value of a hard conjecture like RH or TPC...

Note that Gaifman, On Ontology and Realism in Mathematics, p. 487 does not argue that Π2 sentences of PA, like the twin prime conjecture, are 'true' when undecidable in PA.  He does argue on pp. 500-501 that "an undecidable Π1 sentence
must be true; because a false Π1 sentence is refutable in T."  There is a big difference between Π1 and Π2, because the latter involves an alternation of quantifiers, and therefore cannot be viewed as finitist, on Gaifman's view.  In fact, the twin prime conjecture is Gaifman's prototypical example of an arithmetic statement that, if proved independent, would amount to something of an earthquake ("radical scenario RS"); see page 488 there.  (Just to correct a misconception in the comments.)

Re your "There is a big difference between Π1 and Π2, because the latter involves an alternation of quantifiers, and therefore cannot be viewed as finitist", if we identify Π1 as 1-d integration and Π2 as double integration, then this finitist view would imply the measures of 2-d surfaces aren't decidable and could be independent of analysis (which will be an earthquake event if proved like Godel's incompleteness theorem) while 1-d measure like length is decidable, which seems not that useful for applications like physics where double/triple and higher dimensional integrals are ubiquitous...

@DoubleKnot, I was merely reporting Gaifman's position here.  Do you have a source for your surprising comparison of Pi_k and k-dimensional integration?

See Fubini's theorem for the hidden connection where a double Lebesgue integral is nothing but nested Lebesgue integrals and the process of Lebesgue integration is like the continuous continuation of a mathematical induction on the length of the 1-d domain which is Π1 in nature and the existence of any Lebesgue integral result as a value in its range is like a Σ1 sentence, and Lebesgue integral rather the usual Riemann integral is known to be the right measure to capture physics in nature...

@DoubleKnot, I saw Fubini's theorem but did not find anything there on any connection between Pi_2 statements and double Lebesgue integrals.  It would be helpful if you could clarify what you mean exactly by a Pi_2 statement.

In constructive analysis, the existence of an integral's value can be interpreted as a Σ₁ existential statement and double integral asserts that for every x in the domain we can compute an integral over y like Π₂ sentences in the sense of Lévy hierarchy where AC, GCH, and V=L are all Π₂ sentences. A Lebesgue integral can be seen as an existential statement "There exists a real number I that satisfies the integral condition"...

@DoubleKnot, I looked up Levy hierarchy but there is nothing there about double integrals being Pi_2 sentences.  The existential statement you mentioned for the Lebesgue integral only carries one quantifier and is therefore a Sigma_1 sentence, not a Pi_2 sentence.
